# GeniCam Standard XML format

Tags: c++, c, xml, image, genicam

I am trying to include some configuration XML file that complies with GeniCam standard for a camera application in C. I read GeniCam standard documentation and it is mostly explaining the syntax of the XML file and many details.

Is there a good sample for the Genicam XML file standard that I can use?

After that, the main thing is for the camera application to read the camera condition from the XML file and perform configuring the camera based on that? Or the app is supposed to write into the XML file as well?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Aravis](https://github.com/AravisProject/aravis/), it is an open-source implementation of genIcam and GigEVision. Every real camera will provide its own genIcam XML on-demand (use arv-tool for that), by standard, which defines what parameters can be changed, in what ranges and so on, and how to access them in the camera. The library takes care of setting the new value in the camera, not by writing to the XML, but by updating the settings over the wire.

All `arvgc*` files in the Aravis repository deal with the genIcam procotol (getting and setting camera parameters), `arvgv*` implement the GigEVision protocol (streaming data from the camera), `arvuv*` implement the USB3Vision protocol (USB streaming).

[arv-fake-camera.xml](https://github.com/AravisProject/aravis/blob/master/src/arv-fake-camera.xml) is a good example of a relatively simple XML camera description.